# Python Client is unable to receive data sent from Python Server

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, server, client

I am trying to send some data from my python client to python server 
I have followed this [link](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/)

My python client code is as follows

```
#Socket client example in python

import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print 'Failed to create socket'
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Created'

host = '10.4.1.25';
port = 80;

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((host , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

message = "16973"

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print 'Send failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Message send successfully'

#Now receive data
reply = s.recv(4096)

print reply
```

the python server code is

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 80 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#wait to accept a connection - blocking call
conn, addr = s.accept()

print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

#now keep talking with the client
data = conn.recv(1024)
conn.sendall(data)

conn.close()
s.close()
```

The Function `sendall` is used to send data to client , means when I enter the text in terminal on server I should see it on client as well. But this does not happen

The output which I get is

Server Output

```
$ python server.py
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
Connected with 10.4.1.255:44656
```

Client Output

```
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am unable to know what's going wrong here?

Also how can I send data (message) from Python Client to Python server??

Any help would be great !
Thanks!